# Borrar session Laravel que contiene un array

Tags: laravel

Me gustaría saber si lo estoy haciendo bien, yo quiero borrar 3 sessiones donde en cada de una tengo un array y no se si lo hago de la forma correcta porque me esta dando problemas.

```
public function borrarSessiones(Request $request){
    $request->session()->forget(['cantidades', 'precios2','nombres']);
}
```

Las sessiones las almaceno asi

```
public function factura1(Request $request){
     $precio = $request->precio;
     $nombre = $request->nombre2;
     $cantidad = $request->cantidad;

     $request->session()->push('nombres', $nombre);
     $request->session()->push('precios2', $precio);
     $request->session()->push('cantidades', $cantidad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te debe faltar la llamada al método flush después de borrar los datos de la sesión:

```
$request->session()->forget(['cantidades', 'precios2','nombres']);
$request->session()->flush();
```